# How to drag only one image with iPhone SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to create a little app that takes two images and i want to make only the image over draggable.
After research, i found this solution:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[ event allTouches] anyObject];

    image.alpha = 0.7;

    if([touch view] == image){
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        image.center = location;
    }
```

It works but the problem is that the image is draggable from its center and I don't want that.
So I found another solution:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event { 
    // Retrieve the touch point 
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view]; 
    startLocation = pt; 
    [[self view] bringSubviewToFront:self.view]; 

}


- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event { 
    // Move relative to the original touch point 

    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view]; 
    frame = [self.view frame]; 
    frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x; 
    frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y; 
    [self.view setFrame:frame]; 
}
```

It works very well but when I add another image, all the images of the view are draggable at the same time. I'm a beginner with the iPhone development and I have no idea of how I can only make the image over draggable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `if` condition in the `touchesBegan:` method, See this-

```
-(void)ViewDidLoad
{
    //Your First Image View
    UIImageView *imageView1 = [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150.0, 100.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
    [imageView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"]];
    [imageView1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView1];

    //Your Second Image View
    UIImageView *imageView2 = [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150.0, 200.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
    [imageView2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anyImage.png"]];
    [imageView2 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView2];
}

//Now Use Touch begin methods with condition like this

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    if([touch view] == imageView1)
    {
        CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:imageView1];
        startLocation = pt;
    }

    if([touch view] == imageView2)
    {
        CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:imageView2];
        startLocation = pt;
    }
}

//Use same thing with touch move methods...
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches]anyObject];
    if([touch view] == imageView1)
    {
        CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:imageView1];
        CGFloat dx = pt.x - startLocation.x;
        CGFloat dy = pt.y - startLocation.y;
        CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(imageView1.center.x + dx, imageView1.center.y + dy);
        imageView1.center = newCenter;
    }

    if([touch view] == imageView2)
    {
        CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] previousLocationInView:imageView2];
        CGFloat dx = pt.x - startLocation.x;
        CGFloat dy = pt.y - startLocation.y;
        CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(imageView2.center.x + dx, imageView2.center.y + dy);
        imageView2.center = newCenter;
    }
}
```

These two images will move only when you touch on it and move it. I hope my tutorials will help you.

Comment: what is  startLocation

Comment: **startLocation** is a global variable of **CGPoint** type.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use these two methods

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
     UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
     CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
     myImage.center = location;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down. You should have a main containerView (object of UIView) in your view controller. Within that, you should have `DragableImageView` objects.

`DragableImageView` inherits `UIImageView` and within that, you add your touches code. (Right now you are doing `self.frame = position` which is wrong - and obviously it will move all images at once - because if I understand correctly, you are adding these touches in your view controller).

Create only `DragableImageView` first, test it. Then add two `DragableImageView` instances. test them in different configurations.. you might want to hit test in the `containerView` to see which `DragableImageView` should be dragged (e.g. if you have jigsaw pieces, you might want to pick the one that is at the back rather than the front one).