# Hold the UIView and move only the subview

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiview, subview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIView and over I did a drawing of a geometric figure using CoreGraphics. This geometric figure is added as subview of UIView. 
I intend to use a UIPanGestureRecognizer to move the drawing. Is possible hold the UIView and move just the design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your drawing view is a `UIView`, you can always add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to move it around, like this way:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(drawingMoved:)];    
[_drawingView addGestureRecognizer:pan];
[pan release];
```

Handle the movement like this:

```
- (void)drawingMoved:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSUInteger numOfTouch = [sender numberOfTouches];
    if (numOfTouch==1) {
        CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:_parentView];
        UIView *drawingView = sender.view;
        drawingView.center = point;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this code.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panPiece:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];

    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [yourSubview addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];



- (void)panPiece:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIView *piece = [gestureRecognizer view];



    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[piece superview]];

        [piece setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y + translation.y)];
        [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[piece superview]];

    }

}
```

Implement your code in above method. It will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can write if condition for filtering the moving objects.
see my post at this link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837368/how-to-drag-only-one-image-with-iphone-sdk/10529446#10529446) :-

thank you!